# Geoserver SQL Parameter View

Tags: geoserver, sql

I'm trying to use Geoserver Parameter SQL views, but I'm having trouble getting geoserver to recognize the parameters (and I'm not able to follow the documentation - it's not very clear to me). Here's the code I'm working with so far, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.Date = %Date%
```

I'm trying to get geoserver to recognize each "Date" as a parameter - there are about 25 total dates, and I want the user to be able to select a date (or multiple dates) for display. The dates are in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: as a start I would actually use a different name with respect to the names or attributes in the tables you are joining, at least different casing. Hope that helps,
Simone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a table in PostGIS structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE locations
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  mp_id character varying(50),
  dt timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  the_geom geometry,
  CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

For this table, I make the following Parametric View

```
SELECT id, mp_id, dt, the_geom
  FROM locations where Date(dt)=Date('%Dor%')
```

When you click on 'Guess Parameters from SQL, it will recognise `Dor` as the parameter. You should enter a default value. For my data, I entered `2014-08-19` The main change is in the regular expression. You need to enter `^[\w\d\s-]+$`  this will recognize  dates in yyyy-mm-dd  format.

When you make a WMS request, be sure to send the [parameters properly](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html#using-a-parametric-sql-view). I appended the following to the GET request: `&viewparams=Dor:2014-08-12`

By changing the date, I can see different data in the image sent by `GetMap` request on the WMS end point

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have worked. I was missing the date() portion of the query.